# Applying custom icon to Android project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, icons, drawable

I have a problem with setting my icon to the project. I've created different images and placed them in appropriate folders (drawable 
ldpi, mdpi and so on) and 
`set android:icon` to my icon in AndroidManifest.xml. 
But icons have changed everywhere except  desktop .
Have any ideas why? 
Working in Intellij IDEA

Comment: Can u try uninstall and reinstall the app?

Comment: I've tried. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you have saved the images by some other name. Just copy and replace the `ic_launcher.png` images in all the drawable folders with your own created image.

Comment: Nope, I checked that there are icons with the same name.

Answer (score -2):

I got the same issue just now, but I found a trick to solve this problem:

you can just use the refactor function of intellij and rename the icon again. After renaming intellij will recognize this icon and now make the app again and it works for me!

And I noticed that my application has the correct icon on emulator but not on my android device, but it is because of the android system on the phone. If you see that you icon will be shown up on the emulator correctly then you don't need to get worried.